# why it use return parent.apply(this, arguments) in model

Tags: backbone.js

I don't know  why use it `return parent.apply(this, arguments)` To inherit ?

```
// The constructor function for the new subclass is either defined by you
// (the "constructor" property in your `extend` definition), or defaulted
// by us to simply call the parent constructor.

if (protoProps && _.has(protoProps, 'constructor')) {
  child = protoProps.constructor;
} else {
  child = function(){ 
    return parent.apply(this, arguments); 
  };
}

// Add static properties to the constructor function, if supplied.
_.extend(child, parent, staticProps);

// Set the prototype chain to inherit from `parent`, without calling
// `parent` constructor function.
var Surrogate = function() { 
  this.constructor = child; 
};
Surrogate.prototype = parent.prototype;
child.prototype = new Surrogate;
```

Comment: Read and understand what [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) does and see if it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is strictly related how the Javascript object extension and inheritance is working. In Javascript to extend an object with new properties you have to extend it's base prototype.

Here is a small snippet with the most widespread and and elegant inheritance method. There are other prototypal inheritance methods, the best know is **Crockford's** inheritance method (see below).

```
// Classical (the best to use)
Surrogate = function () {
    Parent.call(this);
    this.type = 'Child Element';
    //... other properties
};

Surrogate.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
Surrogate.prototype.constructor = Surrogate;

Surrogate.prototype.copy = function (source) {

    Parent.prototype.copy.call(this, source);       

    return this;
};
```

Crockford inheritance method:

```
function object(o) {
    function F() {}
    F.prototype = o;
    return new F();
}
```

So coming back to your question. The only difference between `apply` and `call` is that the first one require an array of arguments as parameter. With apply, you can use an array literal, for example,

```
fun.apply(this, ['eat', 'bananas'])
```

or an Array object, for example:

```
fun.apply(this, new Array('eat', 'bananas')).
```

For a thorough explanation check this article:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

The `extend` function does the same thing: extend the parent object with extra parameters.

```
return this
```

returns the object instance on which the method has been called, and is used for methods chaining. So you could call multiple methods at once on the same instantiated object:

```
var surrogate = new Surrogate();
surrogate.copy().delete();
```

Comment: Thank you  for  help , I  am from China and  student  JS short time 。 I can  speak  little English

Comment: if I  don't return this .  what is different ？

Comment: If you think my answer does satisfy your question please accept it.